# Catching my app link to google play

Tags: android, deep-linking

How can i make my app catch a link to google play, but only to my app?
I know how to catch any google play link, but I can't make it specific to my app.

For example: I would like to catch only this link: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Slack

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: ?id=yourAppPackageName

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no way to filter query params in data elements.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element